# How to have an if() split by && and not ||

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm trying to do something like this in c++

```
If x is equal to either a or b or c
and y is equal to either d or e or f
and z is equal to either g or h or i, it would turn true and execute the code
```

I am a bit lost in this

```
if(x==a||x==b||x==c && y==d||y==e||y==f && z==g||z==h||z==i){
 // Do x
}
```

Comment: Can you provide pseudocode and what you expect to obtain?

Comment: Even though answers have already been provided, it is not common to see if-statements of that length; also it is more difficult to read.

I have provided an alternative but similar solution also using the same strategy, except that it uses bool variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the previous answers, the important point is that in C++, you missed that the AND operator `&&` has a **higher operator precendence** than the OR operator `||`.

This can be compared to how the multiplicative operators `*`, `/`, `%` of numbers have higher precedence than additive operators `+` and `-` in algebra.

**Regroup** the parathetheses so you have these three requirements of what x, y, and z have to be, and the statement is true when all three are correct. (Technically, this is called a product of sums form, as the if statement requires the truth of all three smaller statements (the AND), where each of the smaller statement uses only OR statements.).

```
if((x==a||x==b||x==c) && (y==d||y==e||y==f) && (z==g||z==h||z==i)){
 // Do x
}
```

Your original code would be equivalent to

```
if(x==a || x==b || (x==c && y==d) || y==e || (y==f && z==g) || z==h || z==i){
 // Do x
}
```

For larger if-statements, you can also use newlines but of course that will take up more lines.

```
if((x==a||x==b||x==c) 
&& (y==d||y==e||y==f) 
&& (z==g||z==h||z==i)
&& ... other conditions)){
 // Do x
}
```

If you do not want such cumbersome and long if-statement notation, you can consider breaking into logical tests (the if-condition is the "product" of the logical tests), namely

```
bool a1 = (x==a||x==b||x==c);
bool a2 = (y==d||y==e||y==f);
bool a3 = (z==g||z==h||z==i);
bool a4 ...
if (a1 && a2 && a3 && a4 && ..) {
  // Do x
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use `&&` and `||`, with parentheses to make the grouping clear.

```
if ((x == 'a' || x == 'b' || x == 'c') 
    && (y == 'd' || y == 'e' || y == 'f')
    && (z == 'g' || z == 'h' || z == 'i')) {
    // execute code
}
```

Comment: Oh i feel so stupid. How didn't i think of using parenthses lol. Thank you

Comment: You could make the grouping even *clearer* (more readable IMNSHO) if you lined up the sub-conditions (put some spaces between the two opening parentheses).

Comment: @paxdiablo Good point. Sid S's answer already shows it nicely lined up, along with more complete explanation. Upvote him instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at [C++ operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) you'll find that `&&` has higher precedence than `||`.

That means that your `if` statement

```
if(x==a||x==b||x==c && y==d||y==e||y==f && z==g||z==h||z==i)
```

is the same as

```
if (x == a || x == b || (x == c && y == d) || 
    y == e || (y == f && z == g) || 
    z == h || z == i)
```

By using parentheses, you can change it to work the way you want:

```
if ((x == a || x == b || x == c) && 
    (y == d || y == e || y == f) && 
    (z == g || z == h || z == i))
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a straightforward translation from what you said to C++ code:

```
if ((x == a || x == b || x == c) &&
    (y == d || y == e || y == f) &&
    (z == g || z == h || z == i))
{
}
```

Most real programs don't have conditionals this complex. Split up your logic into logical tests.

Comment: @SidS In this case why not? Not many differences between C and C++ in this neck of the woods.

Answer (score 0):

**Try using parentheses to separate your questions:**

```
if( (condA || condB || condC) && (condD || condE || condF) && (...)) and so on.
(condA = condition A)
```

Answer (score -1):

Going a little overboard here (but just a bit):

```
if (element_of(x, {a, b, c}
    && element_of(y, {d, e, f})
    && element_of(z, {g, h, i}))
{
    foo();
}
```

with `element_of` defined as:

```
template <class T>
auto element_of(const T& element, std::initializer_list<T> list) -> bool
{
    return std::find(list.begin(), list.end(), element) != list.end();
}
```

---

Or a even a little bit more overboard (this is just for fun, I don't recommend it):

```
if (Elem{x}.element_of({a, b, c})
    && Elem{y}.element_of({d, e, f})
    && Elem{z}.element_of({g, h, i}))
{
    foo();
}
```

with `Elem`:

```
template <class T> struct Elem
{
    T element;

    auto element_of(std::initializer_list<T> list) -> bool
    {
        return std::find(list.begin(), list.end(), element) != list.end();
    }
};

template <class T> Elem(T) -> Elem<T>;
```

Comment: @DrewDormann readable would be `x element_of {a, b, c}` (the order is important here, syntax could be adjusted)

Comment: This is a good solution, but will probably look like a bunch of arcane tricks to the OP, who simply just needs to figure out operator precedence. :/